# How to prevent child View from parents's onPress

Tags: react-native, touchableopacity

I have TouchableOpacity as follows,

```
 <TouchableOpacity style={{flex: 1, alignItems: center, justifyContent: 'center'}} onPress={() => parentOnPress()}>
    <View style={{height: 50, width: 50}}> 
       
    <View>
 <TouchableOpacity>
```

The `View` inside `TouchableOpacity` occupies small portion at center of the screen and outside of `View` should be the target of parent `onPress` and inside of the `View` should not be target of parent `onPress`.
But in my case when i touch inside `View` parent `onPress` is being called.

How i can prevent child `View` from parent's `onPress`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A workaround could be to replace the `View` with another `TouchableOpacity` that doesn't implement an `onPress`:

```
<TouchableOpacity
  style={{
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'black',
  }}
  onPress={() => {
    // Do something
  }}>
  <TouchableOpacity
    style={{
      height: 50,
      width: 50,
      backgroundColor: 'blue',
    }}>
    {/* Content */}
  </TouchableOpacity>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

---

*I've added some background colors to make it easier to test.*

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with one of my components where i want to disable the touchableOpacity onPress on child objects.
Reason why i couldn't use `pointerEvents='None'` cause my view had a modal inside with some buttons.
I did this

```
<TouchableOpacity
        onPress={disabled ? null : () => {
          console.log('disable dropdown on press');
        }}
        style={styles.root}
      >
        <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={1}>
          <View style={styles.content}>
            {modal}
          </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        
    </TouchableOpacity>
```

P.S.: `activeOpacity={1}` this helps when you don't want to register the touch on your modal so your modal won't grayed out like usual on a touchable opacity component.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding `pointerEvents='none'` to the `View`